# peewee: upsert without primary key or unique constraints

Tags: python, peewee

I have the following sample data in my database:

```
= 'BTCUSDT' and timeframe_id = '30m') or (symbol_id = 'ATOMUSDT' and timeframe_id = '30m');
id          timeframe_id  symbol_id   open_time      open        high        low         close       close_time     base_volume  quote_volume
----------  ------------  ----------  -------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -------------  -----------  ---------------
21          1h            BTCUSDT     1631610000000  45969.99    46200.0     45754.5     45853.87    1631613599999  14494.688    665884011.49137
22          1h            BTCUSDT     1631613600000  45853.88    46085.0     45812.0     46036.14    1631617199999  6797.182     312263363.68921
23          1h            BTCUSDT     1631617200000  46036.13    46157.18    45865.72    45986.45    1631620799999  6843.614     314729653.50406
24          1h            BTCUSDT     1631620800000  45986.45    46647.0     45771.11    46438.53    1631624399999  30800.488    1424879182.6599
405         1h            ATOMUSDT    1631610000000  35.598      35.66       35.029      35.229      1631613599999  814367.91    28761577.13938
406         1h            ATOMUSDT    1631613600000  35.23       35.609      34.371      35.095      1631617199999  1020950.95   35708827.7814
407         1h            ATOMUSDT    1631617200000  35.093      35.908      34.7        34.966      1631620799999  1170633.58   41321501.81656
408         1h            ATOMUSDT    1631620800000  34.971      35.347      34.203      34.978      1631624399999  1031529.26   35908013.68847
17          30m           BTCUSDT     1631617200000  46036.13    46088.0     45923.44    46069.72    1631618999999  2946.376     135544292.71177
18          30m           BTCUSDT     1631619000000  46069.71    46157.18    45865.72    45986.45    1631620799999  3897.238     179185360.79229
19          30m           BTCUSDT     1631620800000  45986.45    46068.0     45771.11    45791.45    1631622599999  6421.929     294839291.18631
20          30m           BTCUSDT     1631622600000  45791.46    46647.0     45780.61    46440.82    1631624399999  24385.586    1130366232.9054
401         30m           ATOMUSDT    1631617200000  35.093      35.908      34.974      35.482      1631618999999  702385.57    24928097.46603
402         30m           ATOMUSDT    1631619000000  35.479      35.534      34.7        34.966      1631620799999  468248.01    16393404.35053
403         30m           ATOMUSDT    1631620800000  34.971      35.347      34.203      34.403      1631622599999  556383.46    19316380.04181
404         30m           ATOMUSDT    1631622600000  34.412      35.212      34.354      34.987      1631624399999  475295.69    16596878.52596
Run Time: real 0.000 user 0.000218 sys 0.000084
sqlite>
```

I need to insert rows of data that could contain some duplicate data among rows.  For instance, `timeframe_id` and `symbol_id` will be duplicates, and `open_time` could be a duplicate, but only on a per `timeframe_id`, per `symbol_id` basis.

I'm trying to add a row using an `upsert`, but I'm running into issues with the various `.on_conflict()` methods I'm trying to use.

`.on_conflict()` using `conflict_target`, `preserve` and `update` (as illustrated in the example code provided below) return `ON CONFLICT clause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint`, which is to be expected based on the schema and the data that is to be `upsert`.

`.on_conflict_replace()` and `on_conflict_ignore()` both inserts a new row, which is not what I want.

Is there a better way to approach this than an `upsert`, or is there perhaps some additional functionality of `upsert` that would allow me to do what I'm trying to do that I'm not seeing?

Code sample:

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse.sqlite_ext import SqliteExtDatabase

db = SqliteExtDatabase('test.db', pragmas={'foreign_keys': 1, 'journal_mode': 'wal'})

class BaseModel(Model):
        class Meta:
            database = db

class Symbols(BaseModel):
    name = CharField(unique=True, primary_key = True)

class Timeframes(BaseModel):
    name = CharField(unique=True, primary_key = True)

class Candles(BaseModel):
    timeframe = ForeignKeyField(Timeframes)
    symbol = ForeignKeyField(Symbols)
    open_time = DateTimeField()
    open = FloatField()
    high = FloatField()
    low = FloatField()
    close = FloatField()
    close_time = DateTimeField()
    base_volume = IntegerField()
    quote_volume = IntegerField()

db.create_tables([Symbols, Timeframes, Candles])

stream={}
stream['data'] = {}
stream['data']['k'] = {}
stream['data']['k']['i'] = '1h'
stream['data']['k']['s'] = 'BTCUSDT'
stream['data']['k']['t'] = 1631610000000
stream['data']['k']['o'] = 45969.99
stream['data']['k']['h'] = 46500.0
stream['data']['k']['l'] = 45700.0
stream['data']['k']['c'] = 45950.00
stream['data']['k']['T'] = 1631613599999
stream['data']['k']['v'] = 6400
stream['data']['k']['q'] = 300000000

try:
    query = (Candles
        .insert(
            timeframe = stream['data']['k']['i'],
            symbol = stream['data']['k']['s'],
            open_time = stream['data']['k']['t'],
            open = stream['data']['k']['o'],
            high = stream['data']['k']['h'],
            low = stream['data']['k']['l'],
            close = stream['data']['k']['c'],
            close_time = stream['data']['k']['T'],
            base_volume = stream['data']['k']['v'],
            quote_volume = stream['data']['k']['q']
            )    
        .on_conflict(
            conflict_target = [
                Candles.timeframe,
                Candles.symbol,
                Candles.open_time,
                Candles.open
                ],
            preserve = [ Candles.timeframe, Candles.symbol, Candles.open_time, Candles.open ],
            update = {
                Candles.high: stream['data']['k']['h'],
                Candles.low: stream['data']['k']['l'],
                Candles.close: stream['data']['k']['c'],
                Candles.close_time: stream['data']['k']['T'],
                Candles.base_volume: stream['data']['k']['v'],
                Candles.quote_volume: stream['data']['k']['q']
                }
            )
        .execute()
    )
except OperationalError as e:
    print(e)
```

Execution:

```
% test2.py
ON CONFLICT clause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint
```

Comment: You need to add a unique constraint on the columns that comprise the conflict target. Simple as.

Comment: @coleifer that's the rub.  I believe I provided adequate output above to illustrate that there is no unique column data among rows in this table, so I can't add a unique constraint to any of them.

Comment: Why can't you put a unique on (Candles.timeframe, Candles.symbol, Candles.open_time, Candles.open)? How is the db supposed to update on conflict if there's no constraint?

Comment: I mean it's right there :)  The data in the database is already not unique, so I can't put a constraint on it :)  Is `update` not the right approach?  I could insert, but that creates another row, which I don't want, so I'm sort of at a loss in the middle of a chicken and egg scenario :)

Comment: I had considered using `Candles.id` since it's guaranteed to be unique, but I'd have to do a query first to get the `id` in order to `upsert` on it.  That process seems expensive, so I pursued the options I've provided in the OP instead.  If it's the only option, then I'll go back to it, but wanted to check in here to see if there's a better way first.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to create a query to find the `id` and include that in the `preserve`[1]

[1]I changed from `SQLite` to `MySQL`, not because it had anything to do wit this issue, but because I was having database locks with the former.  So the formatting of the answer is different than the original question due to the change in the database along the way.

In my ignorance, I do feel this is a heavy and possibly expensive solution, but maybe I'm wrong.

```
try:
    symbols_query = c_db.Symbols.select().dicts()
    for symbol in symbols_query:
        if symbol['name'] == stream['data']['k']['s']:
            symbol_id = symbol['id']
            
    timeframes_query = c_db.Timeframes.select().dicts()
    for timeframe in timeframes_query:
        if timeframe['name'] == stream['data']['k']['i']:
            timeframe_id = timeframe['id']

    current_id = (c_db.Candles
                    .select(c_db.Candles.id)
                    .where(
                        c_db.Candles.timeframe == timeframe_id,
                        c_db.Candles.symbol == symbol_id,
                        c_db.Candles.open_time == stream['data']['k']['t']
                    )
                    .get()
                )

    insert_query = (c_db.Candles
                        .insert(
                            id = current_id,
                            timeframe = timeframe_id,
                            symbol = symbol_id,
                            open_time = stream['data']['k']['t'],
                            open = stream['data']['k']['o'],
                            high = stream['data']['k']['h'],
                            low = stream['data']['k']['l'],
                            close = stream['data']['k']['c'],
                            close_time = stream['data']['k']['T'],
                            base_volume = stream['data']['k']['v'],
                            quote_volume = stream['data']['k']['q']
                            )    
                        .on_conflict(
                            preserve=[ c_db.Candles.id, c_db.Candles.timeframe_id, c_db.Candles.symbol_id ],
                            update = {
                                c_db.Candles.id: current_id,
                                c_db.Candles.timeframe: timeframe_id,
                                c_db.Candles.symbol: symbol_id,
                                c_db.Candles.open_time: stream['data']['k']['t'],
                                c_db.Candles.open: stream['data']['k']['o'],
                                c_db.Candles.high: stream['data']['k']['h'],
                                c_db.Candles.low: stream['data']['k']['l'],
                                c_db.Candles.close: stream['data']['k']['c'],
                                c_db.Candles.close_time: stream['data']['k']['T'],
                                c_db.Candles.base_volume: stream['data']['k']['v'],
                                c_db.Candles.quote_volume: stream['data']['k']['q']
                                }
                            )
                        .execute()
                    )
except peewee.DoesNotExist:
    insert_query = (c_db.Candles
                        .insert(
                            timeframe = timeframe_id,
                            symbol = symbol_id,
                            open_time = stream['data']['k']['t'],
                            open = stream['data']['k']['o'],
                            high = stream['data']['k']['h'],
                            low = stream['data']['k']['l'],
                            close = stream['data']['k']['c'],
                            close_time = stream['data']['k']['T'],
                            base_volume = stream['data']['k']['v'],
                            quote_volume = stream['data']['k']['q']
                            )
                        .execute()
                    )
except peewee.OperationalError as e:
    logging.info(f"{e}")
```